# prevent access to subfolder in apache

Tags: php, apache

currently  I develope forum in php I want from subfolder called webroot to be the main root folder so I used:

```
RewrieEngine On
RewrieEngine ^$ webroot/ [L]
RewrieEngine (.*) webroot/1$ [L]
```

and when I access to it localhost/myforumfolder[this is project folder]
all thing good but when I try to access localhost/myforumfolder/webroot it also works good I want only the first url to work and want to prevent the second (want to be 404 no found)

prevent the second url

Comment: If you don't want to give web access to a folder the best thing to do is to not place that folder in the root web folder. Place it somewhere else on the server.

Comment: If you have access to your apache configuration, just change the document root for less headaches.